# Append a character depending upon the length

Tags: awk

I have a list of lines like

```
50000
12345
2345
12341
3456
```

I want to append a character 0 at the beginning to the lines having only 4 characters so that the result is something like this

```
50000
12345
02345
12341
03456
```

How can I do it efficiently. Don't ask me to use a loop. Is there anything using awk.

Comment: Note that appending 0 to 2345 would yield 23450.  You seem to want to prefix or prepend 0 to yield 02345.

Comment: Through `sub`, `awk 'length($0)==4{sub(/^/,"0")}1' file`

Answer (score 4):

It is tempting to suggest:

```
awk '{printf "%05d\n", $1}' file
```

This prints the first field of the file as a zero-padded 5-digit number.  It will handle inputs such as 1, 23, 456 as well as 2345 (producing 00001, 00023, 00456, 02345).  However, it does assume that the inputs are all numbers; it will not work so well if they're alphanumeric strings, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `length()` function of `awk`.

```
$ awk 'length($0)==4{$0=0 $0}1' file
50000
12345
02345
12341
03456
```

We use the pattern `length($0)==4` to check if the line is 4 characters long. If it is we append `0` in front of it. `1` allows us to print the lines that don't match our criteria as is.